# Find Two Numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $(x+1)(y+1)-1$ is 1 less than a multiple of $5$

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

Two distinct positive integers from 1 to 50 inclusive are chosen. Let the sum of the integers equal $S$ and the product equal $P$. What is the probability that $P+S$ is one less than a multiple of 5?

Here's my logic. We know that $xy+x+y=(x+1)(y+1)-1$. If we need $(x+1)(y+1)-1$ to be $1$ less than a multiple of $5$, we know that $x$ and / or $y$ need to be $1$ less than a multiple of $5$. This means that we have $10*49$ divided by $50*49$. This means our probability is $\frac{1}{5}$. Can someone verify this? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why $xy+y$?  Shouldn't it be $xy+x+y$?

Comment: I will edit this immediately.

Comment: I'm quickly editing my problem. You will see the edited question soon.

Comment: I agree that one of $x,y$ need to be $4\pmod 5$.  As to the probability...well, I'm not sure the problem is well specified.  are all pairs $(x,y)$ equally likely?  Can $x=y$?  Is $(2,3)$ a different choice than $(3,2)$?  Now that you know which pairs are good, it's just a matter of sorting out details.

Comment: I don't think that $(2,3) = (3,2)$

Comment: Well, it's entirely up to you (or to whomever set the problem).  Easiest thing is to say that all $50^2$ possible pairs are equiprobable.  If you go that way, then you just have to count those that have at least one element of the form $5n-1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73686/discussion-between-skupp-and-lulu).

Comment: 890/2450 - some care is needed to avoid double counting. $10\times49$ is clearly wrong because you are only allowing one of $x/y$ to be 4 mod 5.